# Footer not siting at bottom of page

Tags: html, css, wordpress, footer

On my website: http://www.thetechnodaily.com the footer on homepage is fine because of a lot of content. But on pages with small content such as about page its not at bottom of page. The footer is at the end of content rather than bottom of page. Is there any way I can make the footer always stay at bottom?

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to having a fixed footer which always shows at the bottom you will need to use fixed position `bottom: 0px` so it will always stay there even if the content does not fill up the screen

```
 #footer_id {
      position:fixed;
      bottom:0px;
      height: "whatever";
    }
```

Comment: I don't think OP is referring to this. As on the linked webpage, the footer needs to stay under all of the content.

Answer (score 0):

**yea you can use sticky footer**

```
        <div id="footer"></div>

#footer
        { 
        position: relative;
        margin-top: -50px; /* Give the height of footer as negative margin */
        height: 50px;
        clear:both;
        }
```

This link may help you

http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/using-sticky-footer-code.html

Comment: No. I'm not talking about that. See, Like Footer is below content so its always at bottom. But, when content is less, it's still bottom of content but not bottom of screen. I want it to be at the bottom of the screen

Comment: But code didn't work. Can you check code in Firebug and tell me?